# For a random binary sequence of length $2N$ with $n$ 1's, what is the probability that the first $N$ digits have a 'similar' proportion of 1's?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, approximation, law-of-large-numbers

More precisely, if we know the proportion of 1's in a uniformly randomly chosen binary sequence of length $2N$ is $p$, then given an $\epsilon>0$ , what is the probability that the proportion of 1's in the subsequence consisting of the first $N$ digits is $p-\epsilon<p'<p+\epsilon$?

Answers with approximations and bounds are also welcome.

I suspect this is related to the law of large numbers, where we can think of 1's and 0's as denoting the trials that succeeded and failed respectively but I can't think of a precise answer. I also can't use python to check relatively small cases because it quickly becomes computationally unfeasible.

Comment: This is going to be affected by issues such as the parity of $n$ and the discreteness of a hypergeometric distribution, but if $\epsilon \gg \frac1N$ and $p$ is not close to $0$ or $1$ then you might find a normal approximation gets you most of the way.

Comment: Using R: `phyper(n/2+N*epsilon,n,2*N-n,N) - phyper(n/2-N*epsilon,n,2*N-n,N)` where $p=\frac n{2N}$ will calculate $\mathbb P(p-\epsilon<p'\le p+\epsilon)$ using the cumulative distribution function of a hypergeometric distribution.

Comment: @Henry thanks. assuming epsilon is fixed, as N -> infinity, will the result tend to 1 regardless of what p was? it seems to be the case when I try out different parameters in the R program

Comment: Yes it will tend to $1$ for any $p=\frac{n}{2N}$